# Chrome console & ajax to filter net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED message

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, get, console

I want to use ajax on browser console to check a list of URL.

I'm aware about cross domain issue, but I just want to check two status:

if URL returns net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED add 1 to var X
if URL returns any other net::xxxxxx add 1 to var y

So, I need just to know if URL exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the statusCode response:

According to documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> statusCode (default: {}) Type: PlainObject An object of numeric HTTP
>   codes and functions to be called when the response has the
>   corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the
>   response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

I hope to have helped.

Comment: How to use something like  `!=404` ? I did mean, alert only for statusCode different than 404.

Comment: you can use status code 200 (OK) or handle the 'success' callback to do your logic.